# ValueError: script 'H:\Python\Pythontext\games\testprogi.py' not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Выдает эту ошибку.

```
442 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
443 INFO: Python: 3.8.6rc1
444 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
445 INFO: wrote H:\Python\Pythontext\games\testprogi.spec
454 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\для школлы\питон\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 34, in <module>

    sys.exit(load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')())
  File "H:\для школлы\питон\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 94, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "H:\для школлы\питон\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "H:\для школлы\питон\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "H:\для школлы\питон\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "H:\для школлы\питон\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 162, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script 'H:\Python\Pythontext\games\testprogi.py' not found
```

Пробовал много вариантов:

пробовал мудрить с переменой PATH, что-то изменять в самом файле pyinstaller-script, и т.д.

использовал библиотеку Pygame, может важно я не знаю.

Comment: Можете добавить код, с которым у вас возникает ошибка?

Comment: `testprogi.py` нет такого файла. Собственно это и есть ваша проблема да и  весь ответ. Если требуется точнее приведите код. Еще немного коргобит от засовывания python в директории на русском, потом можете получить некоторое кол-во глюков.